# Is it possible to override CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView to return my implementation of ICollectionView?

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource, icollectionview

Is it possible to override CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView to return my implementation of ICollection view for particular collection type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it as default, but you can use CollectionViewSource.CollectionViewType in order to make a specific CollectionViewSource return a certain CollectionView type.